# Trying to center text over image HTML

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

Trying to center text over image in HTML, but my method keeps pushing the text to the very beginning of the page at the top. My method is below...

```css
.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.map-p {
  font-size: 27pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-section">
  <img id="map" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/europe-map-pins-travel-your-planning-trip_255544-1467.jpg?w=2000" alt="Image cannot be displayed" />
  <div class="info">
    <p class="map-p">We have locations all over!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

because .map-section  needs to have position: relative

long answer:
in order for position absolute to use the reference of the parent. the parent needs to have position: relative

so adding

```
.map-section: { position: relative };
```

and fix the transform, should be

```
transform: translate(50%, -50%);
```

will get what you want

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1.) Set `position: relative` to the *parent*  element (`.map-section`) to make it the reference for the absolutely positioned element.

2.) (optionally?) Limit the size of your image to its container's width and add `height: auto` to keep the proportion:

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.map-section {
  position: relative;
}
.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.map-p {
  font-size: 27pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-section">
  <img id="map" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/europe-map-pins-travel-your-planning-trip_255544-1467.jpg?w=2000" alt="Image cannot be displayed" />
  <div class="info">
    <p class="map-p">We have locations all over!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like that
For more info : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

```
.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.map-p {
  font-size: 27pt;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.map-section{  
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would make your answer better.